# Sometimes, I cannot select a vertex as an active element blender 2.8

Tags: selection-tools

Are there any workarounds for when blender (2.8) simply refuses to highlight/select an active element? 
I've set the pivot point to active element and need to scale a plane but very rarely blender actually selects the element I want.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "Blender refuses to select an active element"? The active element is the last-selected object; in other words, if an object is the active item, it is already selected.

Comment: Ok. It works, but the vertex is not highlighted. It's quite frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the "Show overlays" button. Make sure that's active. It's next to the x-ray vision :)